# In PyQt, I need to handle both itemClicked and itemSelectionChanged, but not both at the same time

Tags: pyqt, pyside

I've created a `QTreeWidget` that displays data that's pulled from 3rd party API calls.

I want the data to be fresh when the user either clicks on or uses the arrow keys to navigate to any `QTreeWidgetItem`.  This means making an API call each time the user clicks or uses an arrow key.  Importantly: If the user clicks on the same item a second time, I would like the item to display fresh data (in other words, make another API call and populate with new data, aka refresh)

So far, I've tried:

- connecting both `itemSelectionChanged` and `itemClicked` to the same update function.  This works, but it means that for every click on a new `QTreeWidgetItem`, I get two calls to the update function (one from `itemClicked` and the other from `itemSelectionChanged`), and therefore two API calls that do the exact same thing.  Not ideal.
- Only handling `itemClicked`, but then using an event filter to look for `Key_Up` or `Key_Down` and then manually emitting an `itemClicked`.  The problem with this is that the key event is handled before the selection is changed, so when using the arrow keys, I'm always getting data for the *last* `QTreeWidgetItem` selected, not the current `QTreeWidgetItem`.

I thought about creating a very short timer or a flag and starting/setting at the start of the update function.  If the timer is running or the flag is set, don't run the function (the idea being that the first slot would run, but the second would not because the flag is set/timer is running), but that seems both sloppy and prone to race conditions.

Unfortunately, using a `QTreeView` with a `QAbstractItemModel` is not an option.

With that, is there any way to handle both a repeated click on the same item and arrow keys to select new items without double-calling the same update function?

Comment: You only need `itemClicked` for when the selected item is clicked again - otherwise, `itemSelectionChanged` covers all cases. So keep track of the previous selected item, and ignore clicks when the selection doesn't change.

Comment: @ekhumoro This answers my question.  Thank you.

I'm not sure how to give you credit for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ekhumoro pointed out, this can be done by handling both `itemClicked` and `itemSelectionChanged`, but introducing some logic so that both functions don't run at the same time.

When a user clicks on the widget, an `itemClicked` signal is fired.  When the user changes selection, the `itemSelectionChanged` signal is fired.  In my case, then, I've created two slots (functions): `update` (a slot for `itemSelectionChanged`) and `updateFromClick` (a slot for `itemClicked`).  `updateFromClick` checks to see if the selection has changed (this means you always have to store and keep track of the current selection).  If, in `updateFromClick`, I see that the selection has changed, then I do nothing, as `update` will have been called from `itemSelectionChanged`.  If, in `updateFromClick`, I see that the selection has not changed, I know that `itemSelectionChanged` has not been fired, so I call the `update` function explicitly from `updateFromClick`.

Again, this is just a long-winded version of @ekhumoro's comment that I'm putting here so the question doesn't go unanswered.